# How to set auto-hide for non exists and based on element?

Tags: javascript

Im trying create own vanilla javascript tooltip, but is problem that element (on which running tooltip) can be accidentally deleted and tooltip is not hiding.

```
  function getPosition(obj) {
     /* http://www.boughner.us/kirupa/element_position.html */
     let rect,X=0,Y=0;
     if (obj) {
         rect=obj.getBoundingClientRect();
         X=rect.left + (window.scrollX || window.pageXOffset);
         Y=rect.top + (window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset);
     }
     return {x: X, y: Y}
  }

  function tooltipshow(el, text) {
      var position = getPosition(el);
      var toootip = document.createElement('div'),
      toootip.setAttribute('id', 'tooltip');
      toootip.style.top = position.y + el.offsetHeight;
      toootip.style.left = position.x;
      toootip.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<div class=\"text\">' + text + '</div><div class=\"tail\"></div>');
      document.body.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', toootip);
  }
```

```
<span onmouseover='tooltipshow(this, "tooltip text....")'>text</span>
```

Mouseout can not be used, because during mouseover event may be removed and tooltip is not hidden...

Im thinking about setInterval() but not sure, that is good idea - checking every 0.05s (need to be fast) is unnecessarily burdensome. Some idea?

Comment: How's that tooltip removed anyhow?

Comment: Don't do a timeout. If the tooltip should disappear based on the change of the DOM, then just wait for a change of the DOM. You can utilise a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) for that. You can also listen for events, if that can detect the right condition.

Comment: Why don't you just use one of the myriad of existing tooltip solutions?

Comment: I dont know how - alternative is mouseout with #tooltip + remove() - but how I wrote, here can be problem...

Comment: @Liam small location application based on vanilla js - this question is irrelevant to me, i need solution with custom code, thanks

Comment: @VLAZ interesting solution, I do not know that, if I don't find a simpler solution I'll try, thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    function getPosition(el) {
      let rect,
        x = 0, y = 0;
      if (el) {
        rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
        x = rect.left + (window.scrollX || window.pageXOffset);
        y = rect.top + (window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset);
      }
      return {left: x, top: y};
    }

    function tooltiphide(el) {
      document.querySelector('#' + el.tooltipID).remove();
    }

    function tooltipshow(el, name, text) {
      var position = getPosition(el),
        tooltip = document.createElement('div'),
        tooltipName = 'tooltip-' + name + '-' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 9999999999) + 1;
      el.tooltipID = tooltipName;
      tooltip.setAttribute('id', tooltipName);
      tooltip.setAttribute('class', 'tooltip');
      tooltip.style.top = position.top + el.offsetHeight;
      tooltip.style.left = position.left;
      tooltip.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<div class=\"text\">' + text + '</div><div class=\"tail\"></div>');
      document.body.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', tooltip);
    }
```

```
<span onmouseover='tooltipshow(this, "type1", "tooltip text....")' onmouseout='tooltiphide(this)'>text</span>
```

It's easy hide tooltip by identificator now, call code after DOM was changed:

```
  document.querySelectorAll('div[id^=\"tooltip-type1\"]').remove();
```

@obscure your solution with `el.toolTip="toolTip" + toolTipCounter` was helpful, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could vary the creation of your tooltip a little, to tell the element which causes the generation of the tooltip about it's existence.
Something like

```
var toolTipCounter=0;
      function tooltipshow(el, text) {
          var position = getPosition(el);
          var toootip = document.createElement('div'),
          el.toolTip="toolTip" + toolTipCounter;
          toootip.id=el.toolTip;
          toolTipCounter++;
          toootip.style.top = position.y + el.offsetHeight;
          toootip.style.left = position.x;
          toootip.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<div class=\"text\">' + text + '</div><div class=\"tail\"></div>');
          document.body.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', toootip);
      }
```

So whenever you remove the 'parent' element check if it's **.tooltip** property is not undefined and in case it isn't remove it from the DOM.

```
document.getElementById(el.toolTip).parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementById(el.toolTip));
```

Comment: not just one elem (orange) is removed but all section (purple) - https://i.imgur.com/g8e48j5.png - so it need maybe foreach for second code, maybe?

Comment: document.getElementById(el.toolTip) - el isnt possible identify when whole section (purple) is replaced

Comment: So the span element is actually causing the tooltip and it's parent container - the div - is the element which eventually gets removed? Well in this case change `el.toolTip="toolTip" + toolTipCounter;` to `el.parentElement.toolTip="toolTip" + toolTipCounter;`

Comment: ```el.parentElement``` is also include inside section which is replaced - section DOM is ```el.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement``` - this DOM is retained, replaced is innerHTML

Comment: I found solution I think, ```el.toolTip="toolTip" + toolTipCounter;``` is half way, thanks - when it will be ready, I'll send a solution for others below this thread

Answer (score 0):

Not sure is I got right your question. If you need to detect deletion of the element, you can use [Mutation Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) for detecting element removal.

```
const element = document.getElementById('element');

const observer = new MutationObserver(mutationsList => {
    if(mutationsList[0].removedNodes) {
        console.log('A child node has been removed.');
    };
});

observer.observe(element.parentElement, { childList: true });
```

Comment: if DOM on which running tooltip is removed, that this tooltip will be auto-hide